# How to make Android USB password protected?

Tags: android, android-ndk

I want to make my tablet USB drive password protected so that when some one connect with the USB it will asked for password and if password is matched then only it will access data from the SD Card. In short user will not able to access USB drive without password?

Comment: Thats a tall order, and probably impossible. Encripting the SDCard comes to mind, but then android apps will be unable to access anything on it. If your trying to protect certain things, encript the files in question.

Answer (score 0):

You are welcome to download the Android source code, modify it to have this feature, compile that source code and put it in some ROM mod for your device, then install that ROM mod on your device.

This, of course, would only effectively protect external storage that is not removable. If you truly mean "SD Card", then anyone with sufficient motor skills will be able to remove the card from the device and use its contents as desired.

As Doomsknight notes, you are welcome to encrypt your own app's files on external storage, but that is all you will be able to accomplish using simply the Android SDK.

Comment: I believe that it's possible to provide _transparent_ support similar to [whole disk protection](http://www.symantec.com/whole-disk-encryption). With a ROM mod it is straightforward, even if not easy at all. It might be possible on a regular ROM with root access. There is at least one app on the Play Store that [claims](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.hellcat.droiddev.sgs2devenc) to provide sd card encryotion for some devices without rooting them, but I have not tested it, so I cannot say if it fulfills its purpose.

Comment: It's funny that phone has many security features, but it becomes completely vulnerable when plugged into PC with USB cord. So there is another question: is there a way to make phone "not react" when it is plugged to PC? So it will just charge, not exposing any "interface" to exchange any data , behaving as some "unknown device" PC don't understand how to communicate with. Then I enter password in some app on phone and phone starts to behave as normal.

Comment: @jungle_mole: "is there a way to make phone "not react" when it is plugged to PC?" -- there is nothing for this in standard Android.

Comment: So I can't even switch off MTP functionality, given I have root access? Is this feature that much unneeded or hard (impossible) to implement no one created an application to the moment? o_O. I haven't SD-card slot in my phone so there is no need to encrypt it, just denying phone to exchange data would be enough.. This sucks rly. I mean wtf, it makes no sense.

Comment: @jungle_mole: "So I can't even switch off MTP functionality, given I have root access?" -- possibly, as that would not qualify as "standard Android". Beyond that, this is not a programming question. Please use https://android.stackexchange.com for non-programming Android questions.

Comment: @commonsware why is it not programming question? Actually I'm looking into solving this issue by writing an android application myself.